# Gitlab CI: Cannot find output of build stage

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have my .gitlab-ci.yml file set up in the typical three stages: test, build, deploy. During the build stage, I run a command that compiles my project and puts it in a tarball. The build stage appears to execute successfully because it moves on to the deploy stage, but the deploy stage then says it can't find the tarball. Is it in another directory? What happened to it? Thanks.

Comment: Related https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/10/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-ios-projects/ You can create `artifacts: paths: `. Which allows later on for a download.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that was added after I posted this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each test gitlab-ci clean the build folder, therefore the output files of the build stage are not available in the deploy stage.

You need to rebuild your project also in the deploy stage.

The "stages" are only useful to order your tests, i.e. avoid to try to do a deploy test if a build test failed.

EDIT:
Since Gitlab 8.6, it is possible using [dependencies feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#dependencies)

Comment: Weird. Would it be better to put the compilation in a seperate job? What's the DRY way to do this?

Comment: Oh yes, it would be better, but **at this time** you can not reuse outputs from others stages/tests.

Answer (score 4):

I was surprised to see the same behaviour (on GitLab 8.4).

I use `cmake` to create makefiles, then `make` to build, and then `make test` to run the test. I run all these in a `build/` directory.

I don't want to repeat myself and identify easily which steps are failing. As such, I've created different gitlab-ci *stages*: `cmake`, `make`, `test`, etc. I then tell gitlab-ci to keep the `build` directory using the `cache` option:

```
cache:
    key: "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"
    untracked: true
    paths:
        - build/
```

I think that the `key` option will keep the same build directory for all stages acting on the same branch. See the gitlab-ci doc here: http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#cache

EDIT: Don't use the `cache` for this! GitLab implemented reusable artifacts between stages in 8.4: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/3423
The CI runners will have to be adapted to support this. See: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/336

Comment: I came back to post #3423 but I see you already did. +1. It looks like the feature has been pushed back a few times though.